# Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration numInputRows is 0 but offset is increase

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration ,spark version 3.3 and I found something strange, in the begining I can get right numInputRows ,but about 5 times fetch  numInputRows would be 0 ,bue endOffset is increase ,and I set right checkpointLocation,and
I also try

1. delete checkpointLocation
2. create new Kafka topic
3. change spark version to 3.25

but not work ,and I do not know what to do. My code behind, Thanks

```
 String s=" seq    , actual_voltage    , date    , set_current    , test_time    , set_voltage    , actual_current    , battery_temp1    , battery_temp2    , battery_temp3    , record_no    , actual_power    , setpower    , capacity    , energy    , relative_time    , step_num    , cycle_num    , status    , continuous_time    ,  step_discharge_cap    , step_discharge_energy    , accumulate_charge_cap    , accumulate_discharge_cap    , accumulate_charge_energy    , accumulate_discharge_energy    , max_auxiliary_voltage    , min_auxiliary_voltage    , max_auxiliary_temp    , min_auxiliary_temp    , auxiliary_voltage_diff    , auxiliary_temperature_diff    , total_auxiliary_voltage    , average_auxiliary_voltage    , average_auxiliary_temp    , max_cell_voltage    , min_cell_voltage    , max_cell_temp    , min_cell_temp    , cell_voltage_diff    , cell_temperature_diff    , average_cell_voltage    , average_cell_temp    , energy_judgment_value    , energy_judgment_std_value    , energy_judgment_q_value    , cap_judgment_value    , cap_judgment_std_value    , battery_max_temp    , battery_min_temp    , battery_avg_temp    , max_auxiliary_pressure    , min_auxiliary_pressure   ,pcNo  ,eventId , sendTime , topicCode ,pk ";
        String[] sArray=s.split(",");
        List<String> schemaList=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<sArray.length;i++){
            schemaList.add(sArray[i].trim());
        }


        String schemaString=" seq  STRING , actual_voltage  STRING , date  STRING , set_current  STRING , test_time  STRING , set_voltage  STRING , actual_current  STRING , battery_temp1  STRING , battery_temp2  STRING , battery_temp3  STRING , record_no  STRING , actual_power  STRING , setpower  STRING , capacity  STRING , energy  STRING , relative_time  STRING , step_num  STRING , cycle_num  STRING , status  STRING , continuous_time  STRING ,  step_discharge_cap  STRING , step_discharge_energy  STRING , accumulate_charge_cap  STRING , accumulate_discharge_cap  STRING , accumulate_charge_energy  STRING , accumulate_discharge_energy  STRING , max_auxiliary_voltage  STRING , min_auxiliary_voltage  STRING , max_auxiliary_temp  STRING , min_auxiliary_temp  STRING , auxiliary_voltage_diff  STRING , auxiliary_temperature_diff  STRING , total_auxiliary_voltage  STRING , average_auxiliary_voltage  STRING , average_auxiliary_temp  STRING , max_cell_voltage  STRING , min_cell_voltage  STRING , max_cell_temp  STRING , min_cell_temp  STRING , cell_voltage_diff  STRING , cell_temperature_diff  STRING , average_cell_voltage  STRING , average_cell_temp  STRING , energy_judgment_value  STRING , energy_judgment_std_value  STRING , energy_judgment_q_value  STRING , cap_judgment_value  STRING , cap_judgment_std_value  STRING , battery_max_temp  STRING , battery_min_temp  STRING , battery_avg_temp  STRING , max_auxiliary_pressure  STRING , min_auxiliary_pressure  STRING ,pcNo STRING ,eventId STRING, sendTime STRING, topicCode STRING ,pk STRING";
        ExpressionEncoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(StructType.fromDDL(schemaString));


        SparkSession sparkSession=SparkSession.builder()/*.master("local[*]")*/
                .config("spark.shuffle.useOldFetchProtocol","true")
        
                .config("spark.network.timeout","600s")
                .config("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "hadoop105:9092,hadoop104:9092")
         
                .config("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> dataFrameReader =sparkSession.readStream().format("kafka")
                /*.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")*/
                /*.option("startingOffsets", "latest")*/
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "hadoop105:9092,hadoop104:9092")
                .option("kafka.fetch.max.wait.ms","600000")
                .option("kafka.max.partition.fetch.bytes","82428000")
                .option("kafka.fetch.message.max.bytes","82428800")
                .option("kafka.fetch.max.bytes","80000000")
                .option("kafka.receive.buffer.bytes","3000000")
                .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger","500")
                .option("kafka.group.id","liu_test_group")
                .option("kafka.max.poll.records","500")
                .option("kafka.session.timeout.ms","120000")
            

                .option("subscribe", "hudi_test10_jlv9").load();

        
        Dataset<Row> c11=dataFrameReader.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as("a");
     
        Dataset<TestingDataModal> c22=c11.map(new MapFunction<Row, TestingDataModal>() {
            @Override
            public TestingDataModal call(Row value) throws Exception {

                JSONObject json=JSON.parseObject(value.json());
                String jsonValue=json.get("value").toString();
                TestingDataModal testingDataModal=JSON.parseObject(jsonValue,TestingDataModal.class);
                testingDataModal.setId(IdUtil.fastUUID()+"_"+IdUtil.fastUUID());
                testingDataModal.setSendTime(new Date().getTime());
                return testingDataModal;
            }
        },Encoders.bean(TestingDataModal.class));


       
        Dataset<String> dataString=c22.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<TestingDataModal, String>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<String> call(TestingDataModal testingDataModal) throws Exception {
                String[][] tableValue=testingDataModal.getTableValue();
                String[] titleValue=testingDataModal.getTableTitle();
                List<String> valuesJson=new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i=0;i<tableValue.length;i++){
                    JSONObject jsonRow=new JSONObject(true);
                    for(int j=0;j<titleValue.length;j++){
                        String key=titleValue[j];
                        String value=tableValue[i][j];
                        jsonRow.put(key,value);
                    }

                    jsonRow.put("pcNo",testingDataModal.getPcNo());
                    jsonRow.put("eventId",testingDataModal.getEventId());
                    jsonRow.put("sendTime",IdUtil.fastUUID());
                    jsonRow.put("topicCode",testingDataModal.getTopicCode());
                    jsonRow.put("pk", testingDataModal.getEventId()+"_"+tableValue[i][0]);
                    valuesJson.add(jsonRow.toJSONString());

                }


                return valuesJson.iterator();
            }
        },Encoders.STRING());


        Dataset<Row> rowDataset=dataString.map(new MapFunction<String, Row>() {
            @Override
            public Row call(String value) throws Exception {
                JSONObject jsonObject1=JSONObject.parseObject(value);
                List<String> rowValue=new ArrayList<>();
                for(String schema:schemaList){
                    Object o=jsonObject1.get(schema);
                    if(o==null){
                        rowValue.add("");
                    }else {
                        rowValue.add(o.toString());
                    }
                }

                return RowFactory.create(rowValue.toArray());

            }
        },encoder);





        StreamingQuery query=rowDataset.writeStream().format("org.apache.hudi")


                .options(QuickstartUtils.getQuickstartWriteConfigs())
                .option(HoodieWriteConfig.PRECOMBINE_FIELD_NAME.key(), "sendTime")
                .option(KeyGeneratorOptions.RECORDKEY_FIELD_NAME.key(), "pk")
                .option(KeyGeneratorOptions.PARTITIONPATH_FIELD_NAME.key(), "eventId")
                .option(HoodieWriteConfig.TABLE_NAME, "datas")
                .option("hoodie.datasource.write.keygenerator.class","org.apache.hudi.keygen.ComplexKeyGenerator")
                .option(DataSourceWriteOptions.TABLE_TYPE().key(), HoodieTableType.MERGE_ON_READ.name())
                .option("write.retry.times","10")
       
                .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://hadoop101:8020/hudi_check5")

                .outputMode("append")
                .option("path", "hdfs://hadoop101:8020/hudi_5")
                .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(30000))
                .start();


        query.awaitTermination();
```

Comment: and my commit code is                                                                   /spark/spark-3.2.5-SNAPSHOT-bin-3.0.0-cdh6.3.2/bin/spark-submit --class com.nebula.StreamFromKafka  --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 10g --executor-cores 5 --num-executors 5 --jars $(echo /nebula/hudi_test/spark2/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')   --queue root.default  --conf spark.default.parallelism=20  --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC /nebula/hudi_test/spark-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer, My kafka enable compaction and My test datas use same key to send,and kafka's compaction delete the same key data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).